# window.outerWidth gives wrong value when using Firefox's responsive move

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm hoping there is a workaround for this, as its a bit baffling. In Firefox, you can press `Ctrl+Shift+M`, and it will go into a responsive mode so you can test the different display sizes. This works ok, but this acts a bit weird:

```
window.outerWidth
```

Sample code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/zpasjufs/4/

If you resize the browser properly (outside of the "Responsive View" mode), it correctly shows the right dimensions - *but* if you look at it in "Responsive Mode" and then resize it, the dimension stays the size of the BROWSER (and not the viewport).

Is there a way around this? Please ask if you need more clarification (I'm hoping the demo will show the issue). I don't remember having this issue when using jQuery to get the width of `$(window)`, but I'm not using jQuery in this project.

Comment: Shouldn’t you use `window.innerWidth` then?

Comment: @Xufox - eugh, now I feel stupid! That works like a charm :)